# HTML select not working in kendo grid headerTemplate

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I am adding a drop down (html select) element to the headerTemplate of the kendo grid like so:

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    navigatable: true,
                    pageable: false,
                    height: 430,
                    columns: [ {
                            field: "Date",
                            headerAttributes: { style: "visibility: hidden;" },
                            width:110
                        } ,
                        { field: "PCASS00",
                          width: 100,
                          headerTemplate: '<select id="ddlFilters" name="ddlFilters"><option value="Category">Category</option><option value="Source">Source</option></select><br />PCASS00'},
                        { field: "PPDIAZ9" },
                        { field: "PPDIEUX" },
                        { field: "POIU765" },
                        { field: "P984655" },
                        { field: "PBX5436" },
                        { field: "PUGU7213" }
                    ],
                    editable: true
                });
```

The drop down displays, but it won't expand with the options when I click on it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a *collision* between `click` event handled by `navigatable` set to `true` and the normal behavior of an HTML `select`.

Try setting `navigatable` to `false` (if possible).

Comment: Still not working after setting navigatable to false.  I'm just manually creating a json array for the dataSource , if that helps.  Other ideas?

Comment: Actually it is working...setting navigatable to false did the trick, the problem is that I was opening the html file directly, so I tried actually setting it up on the webserver (IIS), and then it started to work.